# Socket protocol specification for transferring keystrokes?

Tags: sockets, protocols

Is there an existing socket protocol for defining how a way to transfer keystroke data across machines? I want to be able to type on one machine and have what I type there show up on another machine.

For instance, the protocol might the field (eg. that the data is for a keystroke), data type (keystroke), and a value (keystroke value).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could do is look into messaging.  I am not sure if this will help you that much but, there are a lot of different implementations of this but a good place to start is [looking at the JMS API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdr.html).